# data-ng-init doesnt work with the itenary condition

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

I have something like this

```
 <input  type="datetime" 
         data-ng-model="vm.dtPicker" 
         data-ng-init="(@Model.Expiration.HasValue ?  vm.setDate(@Model.Expiration.Value.Year,@Model.Expiration.Value.Month,@Model.Expiration.Value.Day) : vm.setDate('','','')) "
         class="form-control form-control-md date-align"  
         uib-datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy"
         is-open="vm.popup1.opened" 
         popup-placement="bottom-right" 
         ng-required="true" 
         name="Expiration"
         datepicker-options="vm.dateOptions" 
         close-text="Close" 
         show-button-bar="true" 
         close-on-date-selection="true" readonly />
```

Here is the angular function

```
function setDate(year, month, day) {
    vm.dtPicker = new Date(year, month - 1, day);
};
```

I need to call the `setDate` function based on the condition if the Expiration has value or not.

But the problem is `@Model.Expiration.HasValue` returns **true** or **false** but the corresponding `SetDate()` doesn't calls.

Suppose if the Expiration has no value it still calls the `vm.setDate(@Model.Expiration.Value.Year,@Model.Expiration.Value.Month,@Model.Expiration.Value.Day))` and I get the `NullException` error.

If I have the Expiration Date from Model then I should fill the textbox else I must show as null.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Instead using long condition inside `ng-init`, Use a function with it. and do initialization there.

Comment: I am new to angularJS. Could you please give me an example.

Comment: Can you make `jsfiddle` or `plunkr`? Will be helpful.

Comment: I added a function in ng-init like you have asked. It's works perfectly. The problem was in the expression that I added in ng-init. Here is the jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/k0p5qsqo/. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's not your working code. Can you add your controller as working so we can see and figure it out- what issue is there